# Put request angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My put function doesn't work, this is my service

```
updateP(partecipanti: Partecipanti): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.partecipantiUrl, partecipanti, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated p id=${partecipanti.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('update'))
    );
  }
```

in my component I have

```
save(): void {
     if (this.part) {
       this.PartecipanteService.updateP(this.part)
         .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
         alert("Partecipante modificato correttamente")
     }
   }
```

and I call the save function in a button

Comment: And what exactly does not work? Does it throw an error? Does the server return an HTTP error code? Is anything being logged?

Comment: No error But the save button doesn’t work, maybe because My Put in eclipse is localhost:8080/partecipante/id, and here i use only localhost:8080/partecipante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly is happening? do you see all logs?  What do you see in the browser network tab, is the PUT request fired? is the request completed or still pending?

try to add some logs and handle the error anyway:

```js
save(): void {
  console.log('will save');
     if (this.part) {
       console.log('this.part is true');
       this.PartecipanteService.updateP(this.part)
         .subscribe(() => {console.log('ok it works');this.goBack()},
         err => console.error('got an error', err)
);
         alert("Partecipante modificato correttamente")
     }
   }
```

Comment: No error But the save button doesn’t work, maybe because My Put in eclipse is localhost:8080/partecipante/id, and here i use only localhost:8080/partecipante

Comment: well if you use the work URL it will never work! but you should get a 404 error from the backend and still see the request in the browser's network tab

Comment: My console show "will save", "this part is true" ERROR PUT 405 and "ok it works"